# Applescript delimiter addition/modifiction to this code

Tags: applescript

I have this script done, that organize files into subfolders based on their first 6 strings.

For example, `bjaaahdd_123` will be in a subfolder named `"bjaaahd"`. 
This script was tested on dummy files in order to inspect its viability. 
but now, trying to test on the real task. It does not work as intended. 
the files come in this form `"_londondire_123455-901-34"` etc.

I want the "_londondire" part only to be the folder and organized by that name. In another word, only the name without the numbers. 
I read about delimiters, but for the love of god, I don't understand it.

```
--script begins

on run
    set theFolder to ""
    set fileList to {}
    set theTarget to ""
    set theString to ""

    tell application "Finder"
        set theFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose containing folder:" without invisibles and multiple selections allowed)
        set fileList to every file of theFolder

        repeat with i in fileList
            name of i as text
            set theString to text 1 thru 6 of result
            try
                set theTarget to ((theFolder as text) & theString) as alias
                move i to theTarget
            on error
                make new folder at theFolder with properties {name:theString}
                move i to result
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
end run

--script ends
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text item delimiters` is the best way to do that.

With this code

```
set theText to "_londondire_123455-901-34"
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "_"}
set textItems to text items of theText
set text item delimiters to TID
```

the result in the variable `textItems` is a list `{"", "londondire", "123455-901-34"}`, so the desired value is the second text item

```
set theResult to item 2 of textItems -- "londondire"
```

If you need the leading underscore write

```
set theResult to "_" & item 2 of textItems -- "_londondire"
```

Comment: in case there is multiple files with the same style, for example, _londondire , _Parisdire etc.?

Comment: The code splits any string by the underscore characters. The number of underscores is important, not the entire literal text